# how to import modal service in ngx-bootstrap systemjs

Tags: angular, systemjs, ngx-bootstrap

I'm tyring to import BsModalService into my component. But it's throwing 404 as shown below.

I'm importing `BsModalService` in my component as

`import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';`

`GET http://localhost:8000/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):21 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8000/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal.js`

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    constructor(private bsModalService: BsModalService) {}
}
```

**package.json**

`"ngx-bootstrap": "^1.8.0",`

**systemjs.config.js**

```
map: {
     ...
    'ngx-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ngx-bootstrap'
}

packages: {
    ..
    'ngx-bootstrap': { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
}
```

**app.module.ts**

`import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';`

what am I missing here.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in ngx-bootstrap@1.8.1, try it.
Also if you're using system.js you have to import BsModalService like this

```
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```